# Minimum number of strings to cover entire space within Hamming distance

Tags: strings, discrete-mathematics, coding-theory, hamming-distance

Given $(n, k)$:

1. What is the minimum number $x$ of (binary) strings such that all $n$-bit (binary) strings are within $k$ Hamming distance of some string?

   - Is there an asymptotic expansion or lower bound, at least?
   - A somewhat-trivial lower bound is as follows:

     - There's $\sum_{i=0}^{k} {n \choose i}$ strings within distance $k$ of a given string.
     - There's $2^{n}$ strings total.
     - Each string can be counted no less than once.
     - So we have a lower bound of: $$x \ge \frac{2^{n}}{\sum_{i=0}^{k} {n \choose i}}$$
2. Is there an explicit formula that maps an index $1..k$ (or $0..(k-1)$) to these strings? (I am aware that this is likely not unique.)

This is closely related to error-correcting codes, but ultimately distinct. (In an error correcting code you (usually) want to have every string within distance $k$  (or $k/2$, etc, etc) of no more than one codeword, whereas here you want to have every string within distance $k$ of *at least one* codeword.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The object you are interested in is called a [covering code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covering_code). While less popular than error-correcting codes, covering codes share many of the same difficulties. In particular, there is little hope for an exact formula for the minimal size of a covering code.

Comment: That's too bad... Thank you for the answer though!